# How can I crop pictures from an old scanner for a slide show

Tags: crop

I have an HP 3200 all in one scanner that I haven't used in a long time. I had cropped photos  with it.

Now it's saying the Windows7 can't work with it...or visa versa.

What can I use to crop the photos I have scanned. Do I need to load a driver? upload a patch?

I can't even seem to move them onto a thumb drive...Help? Do I need to go to Lynda.com and learn photoshop just to fix these pictures so I can put them on a slide show frame??

Comment: If the problem is that Win 7 can't use the scanner, go to the HP web site and download the latest drivers.  If you have existing pictures to crop, you can do that with a variety of software.  Matt's response talks about MS Paint.  If you want to do more cleanup and fine-tuning that simply cropping, you don't need Photoshop.  Look at Irfanview (www.irfanview.com), which is a great free program that can do most simple editing, conversions, batch processing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's a crude solution but you can just use `paint.exe` if you are trying to crop a basic image. You can find Paint under Programs > Accessories > Paint. Just open your picture in Paint and you will see the selection and crop tools in the upper bar.

[image: Snippet from Paint]

If you are comfortable with program better suited for this task you could always download Paint.Net or IrfanView which are both free.